# Откат state в react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

В моем, небольшом, приложении, `state` фильтруется при нажатии на кнопку, фильтров,  и соответственно, кнопок несколько.

Мне необходимо при повторном нажатии на кнопку фильтра скидывать этот фильтр, но я понимаю лишь как скинуть все фильтры сразу (просто переприсвоить `state`) как лучше это реализовать?

```
class App extends Component {

constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state = {items:TransactionArr }
}

resetsortVal = () => this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter(w => w.value >1000 )})
sortVal = () => this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter(w => w.value < 1000 )})  
sortTypeByIncome = () => this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter(w => w.type === "income") })
sortTypeByConsumption = () => this.setState({items:  this.state.items.filter(w => w.type === "consumption") })
sortDate = () => this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter(w => w.dt.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()) })

render() { 
let baseState = this.state;
return (
  <div className="App">
    <table border = "1" cellSpacing="0" >
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><Btn sortType ="value" toDoMeth={ this.sortVal } btnname={"value"} /></td>
        <td>
          <Btn sortType ="type" toDoMeth={ this.sortTypeByIncome} btnname={"sortTypeByIncome"} />
          <Btn sortType ="type" toDoMeth={ this.sortTypeByConsumption} btnname={"sortTypeByConsumption"} />
        </td>
        <td><Btn sortType ="date" toDoMeth={ this.sortDate} btnname={"date"} /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th><p>id</p></th> 
       <th><p>value</p> </th>
       <th><p>type</p></th> 
       <th><p>date</p></th>
      </tr>
       {this.state.items.map(obj =><tr key = {obj.id}><td >{obj.id}</td><td>{obj.value}</td><td>{obj.type}</td><td>{obj.dt.toString()}</td></tr>)}
      </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
 )
}     

};
export default App;
```

Comment: Я бы сделал один метод фильтра, в который бы передавал предикат, а в стейте хранил бы примененные фильтры, а сами фильтры (предикаты) можно сделать как свойство класса. Чтобы отменить фильтр при повторном клике, нужно знать о том, что фильтр уже применен. Если идти вашим путем, то получится, что применив один фильтр - будут сброшены другие.

Comment: Я думал примерно так сделать, но там выходит что нужно нагромождать конструкцию из if, ведь фильтра 4 и 2^4=16 методов получится 
иначе я не вижу вариантов